# what are minimal requirements for iphone application to be considered localized

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, localization, info.plist

I need my application to be considered localized in order for MFMailComposer to present its fields in localized language. I don't need to localize any strings or xibs. What is the minimum I need to do in order for my application to be considered localized?

TIA

Comment: MFMailComposer does that automaticaly, no need to do anything to your code. Just build, change your settings and check for yourself.

Comment: Probably I need some minimal settings to support localization. Currently MFMailComposer shows in english for any localization, so what should i add to my plist in order for MFMailComposer to understand, that now it's another localization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all localization is the process of making your app work in a specific locale or language. i.e. this usually means translating user strings and XIBs. Internationalization is making your app work properly in any locale, i.e. using `NSDateFormatter` etc. to format dates and times according to the user's settings.

I think MFMailComposer should use the user's currently selected locale/language to display its fields so you shouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: should i localize the view, that i set as its delegate?